# jest test. How do you test function call within a function from same module?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using Jest to test in my project.

Here is my situation.

```
//myModule.js

export const funcA = () =>{};
export const funcB = ()=>{
  funcA();
}
```

```
//myModule.test.js
import {funcA,funcB} from './myModule'

describe("funcB",()=>{

  it ("should call funcA",
    ()=>{
     funcB(); // execute b function
     expect(funcB).toHaveBeenCalled(); // hypothetically I would like to do this. check funcA
    }
  )
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this? My current situation does not allow me to pass funcA as argument of funcB.

Any thoughts and ideas will be helpful!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`myModule.ts`:

```js
export let funcA = () => {};
export const funcB = () => {
  exports.funcA();
};
```

`myModule.test.ts`:

```js
import * as mod from './myModule';

describe('funcB', () => {
  it('should call funcA', () => {
    jest.spyOn(mod, 'funcA');
    mod.funcB();
    expect(mod.funcA).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60221752/myModule.test.ts (8.763s)
  funcB
    ✓ should call funcA (3ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 myModule.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.308s
```